# How to decompose python line of code and filter out data?

Tags: python, filter

I have below line of code which I want to filter out only ones with numeric values and skip None/Null ones. How can I do that?
thanks in advance.

**values = [cell['Value'] for cell in data.values()]**

```
import configparser

from TM1py.Services import TM1Service

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(r'..\config.ini')

with TM1Service(**config['tm1server01']) as tm1source:
    with TM1Service(**config['tm1server02']) as tm1target:

        mdx1 = """
            SELECT non empty {Descendants([plan_version].[plan_version].members,100,LEAVES)} *
            {[plan_business_unit].[plan_business_unit].[10120]} *
            {[plan_department].[plan_department].[415] } *
            {[plan_chart_of_accounts].[plan_chart_of_accounts].[64055] } *
            {[plan_exchange_rates].[plan_exchange_rates].[local] } *
            {[plan_lines].[plan_lines].[line 1] }
            on 0, 
                   {[plan_time].[plan_time].[Dec-2004]} on 1 
                   FROM [plan_BudgetPlanLineItem]
            """

        mdx2 = """
                   SELECT non empty {[plan_version].[plan_version].[FY 2004 Budget]} *
                   {Descendants([plan_business_unit].[plan_business_unit].members,100,LEAVES)} *
                   {Descendants([plan_department].[plan_department].members,100,LEAVES) } *
                   {Descendants([plan_chart_of_accounts]. 
                   [plan_chart_of_accounts].members,100,LEAVES) } *
                   {[plan_exchange_rates].[plan_exchange_rates].[local] } *
                   {Descendants([plan_lines].[plan_lines].members,100,LEAVES) }
                   on 0, 
                   {[plan_time].[plan_time].[Dec-2004]} on 1 
                   FROM [plan_BudgetPlanLineItem]
                   """

        data = tm1source.data.execute_mdx(mdx1, cell_properties=['Value'])

        values = [cell['Value'] for cell in data.values()]

        tm1target.data.write_values_through_cellset(mdx1, values)

       # this for loop returns 1 row when MDX1 is used and that data does move to
       # the target server. Using MDX2 returns 13 rows but the values listed do not appear
       # in the target server
        for x in data.values():
            print(x['Value'])
```

Comment: Please provide an input and output of what you are currently working on for a better understanding.

Comment: added complete code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can filter numerical-only values inside the list-comprehension:

```
values = [
    cell['Value']
    for cell in data.values()
    if isinstance(cell['Value'], (int, float))
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain a bit.  I think if isinstance(cell['Value'], (int, float)) line is meant to include only the ones with numeric?

Answer (score 0):

if cell is a dataframe:

```
values = cell['values'].notnull().tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. 
Are we able to expand / break down this code to multiple lines? and is this statement called python lambda or list comprehension? I am super new to python

Comment: my answer was before you added the code, I thought you were asking about dataframes and I jumped into it so quickly
I'm new to coding , sorry I can't help on this one

Comment: The code works ok, I just wanted to know how to expand the code (specifically that line). Whatever you've responded was helpful so thanks!